# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (784,)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, pickle

I have a script to create a pickle file from images. Before dumping, i am normalizing the images like this:

```
mu = np.mean(all_data.astype(np.float32), 0)
print("mu:", mu)
sigma = np.std(all_data.astype(np.float32), 0)
for device_id in range(400):
    X_train[device_id] = np.array(X_train[device_id])
    X_test[device_id] = np.array(X_test[device_id])

for device_id in range(400):

    X_train[device_id] = (X_train[device_id].astype(np.float32) - mu) / (sigma + 0.001)
    X_test[device_id] = (X_test[device_id].astype(np.float32) - mu) / (sigma + 0.001)
    X_train[device_id]=X_train[device_id].tolist()
    X_test[device_id] = X_test[device_id].tolist()

return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test
```

when i run the script, i get the following error:

```
File "generate_data_mata_learning.py", line 80, in generate_dataset
    X_train[device_id] = (X_train[device_id].astype(np.float32) - mu) / (sigma + 0.001)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (784,)
```

which i am guessing is caused by numpy array. But can not find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post the full code so that this problem can be reproduced? What are the exact shapes of `X_train` and `X_test` that is being passed to this function? You probably need to post the full function with an example input that is causing this issue.

Comment: Also, does each element of `X_train` have the same shape? If so, there is probably much better ways of doing this. I am guessing each element of `X_train` has diffeernt shape which is why you are handling them separately. Right?

Comment: the full code can be found here: https://github.com/ddayzzz/federated-meta/blob/master/dataset/omniglot/generate_data_mata_learning.py

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stackoverflow. A suggestion, please go through the community guidelines on posting a good question. This is important because if your code is not following the guidelines, it tends to get ignored by the community. specifically, your code needs to be reproducible (someone should be able to copy-paste your code, run it and reproduce the error). You have given a link to the full github repo which is also not really helpful unfortunately because if someone has to clone a massive repo to reproduce your issue, they aren't likely going to do it.

Comment: If you want help, you need to reduce the problem to it's smallest component that still causes the issue. And this processes is important because when doing this, you will likely find the issue on your own. 

In the link that you gave, the function relies on a directory named `raw/1623_characters` for that function to be run. So that file is also not self-contained, unfortunately. 

Please see the "Help others reproduce the problem" section of this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (784,)`, `X_train[device_id]` or `mu` might be empty.